# Unable to load a previous revision of a question/answer when editing

Tags: bug, edits, revision-history

Shift-click `Edit` on a question or an answer. A new window appears, with a dropdown for existing revisions.

Select a previous revision from the dropdown. Nothing happens (the new text is not loaded into the editor, the preview does not change, the warning message "you are editing a previous revision" does not appear).

Makes rolling back [stupid things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25070945/11683) difficult.

Reproduced with IE8 and Firefox 31.

Comment: I wonder if they've deprecated that dropdown, since just regular-clicking Edit does some JavaScript and no longer provides the dropdown.

Comment: @Rawling Shift-clicking was specifically to get the dropdown, and the javascript on regular click has been around for ages.

Comment: OK so the functionality where you go to `[post]/edit/[revision-id]` still works (I guess it's still used from the revision history), but the `change` event that is supposed to attach to that dropdown no longer attaches. The selector used is `#revisions-list` but the dropdown does *not* have `revisions-list` as an `id`, just as a `name`.

Comment: Also occurs with Chrome.