# Revision selection in Question editing does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, edits, revision-history

The Revision selection dropdown-list in the question-editing screen does not appear to function any more. Previously, the question contents editbox would be filled with the contents of the selected revision, but now nothing happens.

Is this broken or an intentional change? Browser: Chrome on Windows (latest stable).

I think the same question has been asked [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267916/unable-to-load-a-previous-revision-of-a-question-answer-when-editing), but it has received no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that has been broken since last July. Shows how rarely-used a feature that is :) Fixed in the next build, thanks.

Comment: I was beginning to think no one saw this post, or no one cared :P Thanks for the response.