# How do I earn the "clean up" badge? What is a rollback?

Tags: support, badges

What does the Clean Up/Rollback badge mean?  It says I can get it by making my first roll back. What does it mean by first roll back?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing  look for rollback. It's basically cancelling an edit

Comment: @Patrice are rollbacks available to suggested editors?  I can never remember.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I THINK that it's only on your own posts while you're < 2K

Comment: Wait I can test this on MSE.

Comment: Uber-Meta dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038/248731

Comment: If I edited someone's posts, can I roolback ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the [Edit Help Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) (thanks Patrice):

> What is a rollback?
>
> A rollback reverts a question or answer to a previous version in the edit history. The rollback action itself then appears as the most recent item in the edit history.

What that page doesn't tell you is that **you can submit rollbacks to posts where you can immediately apply edits without review**<sup>1</sup>.  Once you can edit other posts without needing to go through the review queue, you can rollback edits by choosing that option in the edit history.  For most posts, this means you need to earn the [Edit Questions And Answers Privilege at 2k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).  The exceptions are posts you own (which you can always edit) and community wiki posts if you have [the 100 reputation privilege to edit community wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki).

To get the edit history,  use the link at the bottom center of the post with something like [edited (time)] or visit `{site}/posts/{postId}/revisions`

> [image: Edit link]

Then, if you can edit the post without requiring review, you can select the revision you want and rollback to that revision:

> [image: Rollback link]

---

<sup>1</sup> As [Kendra points out in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307582/how-do-i-earn-the-clean-up-badge-what-is-a-rollback/307587?noredirect=1#comment255680_307587), you can effectively roll a post back by manually suggesting an edit that's based off a previous revision.  Select the revision you want to use as the starting point for your edit from the dropdown and then make additional edits as needed.  Note that this counts as an edit and not as a rollback, so you won't earn the badge this way.

Comment: Actually, <2k editors _can_ rollback an edit- On the edit screen, there is a dropdown at the top that is labelled "Rev" and lists all the revisions of a post. When switched, it changes the text in the edit box to that of a previous revision, and from there the text can be further edited or (I assume without actually testing) just submitted as a straight rollback edit. Naturally, an edit comment would have to be made. [This was broken for a while,](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290916/revision-selection-in-question-editing-does-nothing) but was fixed recently.

Comment: See also [this answer which mentions using the dropdown.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268340/2607247)

Comment: @Kendra wow I had no idea.  Just curious, does it count as a "rollback" or is it just another suggestion that uses the dropdown to autofill the edit.  Reading that answer, it seems that "manual rollbacks" aren't considered rollbacks?

Comment: It's technically a rollback in the sense that it goes back to a previous revision, but it's done manually, more edits can be applied simultaneously, and you'd be able to add a custom comment this way. I don't actually know a lot about it, as I've never had a reason to use this feature myself, I just know it exists. Pretty sure it doesn't count for the badge, this was more just interesting bonus information I don't think a lot of people know about.

Comment: I'm not sure you'd get the badge... but it's still useful to know so I'll update.

Comment: you have explained very well.